# How to return this Future<Widget> as Widget inside Streambuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the function which i s going to return as `Future<widget>,` now the problem i am facing is i am calling the function inside `Stream builder`, how will i get the future widget function

**here is my function**

```
 Future<Widget> overlapped(Map id) async {
    final overlap = 16.0;
    List liImage = [];
    final result = await firestore.collection('community').doc(id['id']).get();
    final listofMembers = result.data()!['members'];

    setState(() {
      liImage = listofMembers;
    });
    if (liImage.isNotEmpty) {
      final imag = liImage.map((e) async {
        final imageList = await firestore.collection('users').doc(e).get();
        final im = imageList.data()!['picture'];
        return im;
      });

      final items = imag
          .map<Widget>(
            (e) => CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage('e'),
            ),
          )
          .toList();
      List<Widget> stackLayers = List<Widget>.generate(items.length, (index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(index.toDouble() * overlap, 0, 0, 0),
          child: items[index],
        );
      });
      return Stack(children: stackLayers);
    } else {
      return SizedBox();
    }
```

i am calling the function here in the StreamBuilder

```
 Expanded(
                            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map>>(
                                stream: firestore
                                    .collection('community')
                                    .where('members', whereNotIn: [
                                      auth.currentUser!.uid,
                                    ])
                                    .limit(10)
                                    .snapshots(),
                                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                  
                                  return ListView.separated(
                                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 15,
                                          ),

                                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                       
                                        return GestureDetector(
                                         
                                          child: Container(
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                                topRight: Radius.circular(6.0),
                                                bottomLeft:
                                                    Radius.circular(6.0),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            child: Stack(children: [
                                              Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Container(
                                                    width: 152.0,
                                                    height: 48.0,
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                          BorderRadius.only(
                                                        topLeft:
                                                            Radius.circular(
                                                                6.0),
                                                        topRight:
                                                            Radius.circular(
                                                                6.0),
                                                      ),
                                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                        image:
                                                            CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                                          sugComm['comImage'],
                                                          errorListener: () =>
                                                              Icon(Icons.error),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    height: 30.0,
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    // 'Wack movies',
                                                    sugComm['comName'] ?? '',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 15.0,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w600,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    height: 10.0,
                                                  ),
                                                  overlapped(sugComm),
                                                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                                                  Text(
                                                    sugComm['members'].length ==
                                                            0
                                                        ? '${sugComm['members'].length ?? 0} Member'
                                                        : '${sugComm['members'].length ?? 0}+ Members',
                                                  ),
                                                  ElevatedButton(
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                      firestore
                                                          .collection(
                                                              'community')
                                                          .doc(sugComm['id'])
                                                          .update({
                                                        'members': FieldValue
                                                            .arrayUnion([
                                                          auth.currentUser!.uid
                                                        ])
                                                      });
                                                    },
```

Comment: use `Stream.asyncMap` method - the docs say: *"Creates a new stream with each data event of this stream asynchronously mapped to a new event."*

Comment: @pskink can look at the code above and structure your, the code i have stream keep calling it several times

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for this.

Here is an example usage:

```
FutureBuilder<Widget>(
  future: overlapped(sugComm),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return snapshot.data!;
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("There is an error: ${snapshot.error}");
    } else {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
  },
);
```

However, it is more common to await for your data from Firestore rather than a `Widget`.

Let's say that your `overlapped()` returns a `List<String>` for instance. This is what it would then look like:

```
FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
  future: overlapped(sugComm),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      final items = snapshot.data!
          .map<Widget>(
            (e) => const CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage('e'),
            ),
          )
          .toList();
      List<Widget> stackLayers =
          List<Widget>.generate(items.length, (index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(index.toDouble() * overlap, 0, 0, 0),
          child: items[index],
        );
      });
      return Stack(children: stackLayers);
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("There is an error: ${snapshot.error}");
    } else {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: The stream is affecting it... it keep calling that serval times because of the stream